# Fitting a long equation in tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, equations, tcolorbox

I am trying to fit a long equation in a `tcbtheorem` environment. The problem is, the equation sticks out the box on the right side. How do I fix this? I'd prefer to not use `multline` to break the equation into multiple lines (it just isn't aesthetically pleasing to me). I also tried using `\scriptstyle`, but then the math becomes too small compared to the text in the theorem box. Ideally, either I'd like to expand the width of the tcbtheorem box a bit on either side, and slightly shrink the font size of the equation so that it fits. However, I am open to other suggestions that look nice.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}


%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


\newtcbtheorem[]{mylemmma}{Lemma}{colframe=green,colback=white, width=\textwidth}{lem}
\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=white}  
\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mylemmma}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\begin{frame}

    \begin{mylemmma}{Name of the Lemma}{lem}
        The function changes as follows. 
        \[-f(\sum_i g(-\psi - b)) \geq -f (\sum_i g(-\psi)) + \sum_i (b_i - h_i)^\top \left( \frac{g(-b)}{\sum_i g(-b)} \right) - error\]
%       \[{\scriptstyle -f(\sum_i g(-\psi - b)) \geq -f (\sum_i g(-\psi)) + \sum_i (b_i - h_i)^\top \left( \frac{g(-b)}{\sum_i g(-b)} \right) - error}\]
%\begin{multline*}
%   -f(\sum_i g(-\psi - b)) \\
% \geq -f (\sum_i g(-\psi)) + \sum_i (b_i - h_i)^\top \left( \frac{g(-b)}{\sum_i g(-b)} \right) - error
%   \end{multline*}
    \end{mylemmma}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I had already upvoted the question but I have no good proposal. Personally I would go with `multline`  and company.

Comment: Thank you! What is "company"?

Comment: For instance, `align*` with or without `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the left margin in the `\tcolorbox`, some spacing adjustments, and a medium sized formula; is it better?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
% \usetheme{default} % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
% \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
% \usefonttheme{default} % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{nccmath}

%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[]{mylemmma}{Lemma}{colframe=green,colback=white, width=\textwidth, left=0pt}{lem}
\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=white}
\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mylemmma}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\begin{frame}

    \begin{mylemmma}{Name of the Lemma}{lem}
        The function changes as follows.
      \[\medmath{-f(\sum_i g(-\psi - b)) \geq -f \Bigl(\sum_i g(-\psi)\!\Bigr) + \sum_i (b_i - h_i)^{\!\top}\! \biggl( \frac{g(-b)}{\sum_i g(-b)} \biggr) - error} \]
    \end{mylemmma}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Bernard! I'll accept your answer. Unfortunately, the actual f and g I'm using in my slide are functions like exp and log, due to which the above expression is in fact even longer than now. This leads the equation to still spill out of the box.

Comment: One followup question: is it possible to use medmath with multline? I am trying to do so, but it's throwing compilation errors. I think that might be the nicest option for me.

Comment: I found it! So, thanks to Schrodinger's cat's comment above and your answer here, I was able to find the perfect way for me: I used \equation*, then \medmath, then \multlined (in mathtools package). It looks much better!

Comment: I guess `\medmath{...}` cannnot have  line breaks. But there's also a `medsize` environment. If you're interested, you should have a look at the package documentation. I often use the `\mfrac` command, when I have a numerical fraction as coefficient and I feel it shouldn't have the same size as fraction expressions.